# How to use access token in identityserver4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

The scenario is my client's possibility to grab data about my users. There is the code for config server:

Startup.cs

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
         .AddTemporarySigningCredential()
         .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(ApiConfiguration.GetIdentityResources())               .AddInMemoryApiResources(ApiConfiguration.GetAllResources())
         .AddInMemoryClients(ApiConfiguration.GetAllClients())
         .AddTestUsers(ApiConfiguration.GetUsers())
```

ApiConfiguration

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetAllResources()
        {
            yield return new ApiResource
            {
                Name = "customAPI",
                Description = "Custom API Access",
                UserClaims = new List<string> { "role" },
                ApiSecrets = new List<Secret> { new Secret("scopeSecret".Sha256()) },
                Scopes = new List<Scope> {
                    new Scope("customAPI"),
                }
            };
        }
public static IEnumerable<Client> GetAllClients()
        {
            yield return new Client
            {
                ClientId = "oauthClient",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                ClientSecrets = new List<Secret> {
                    new Secret("Password".Sha256())},
                AllowedScopes = new List<string> { "customAPI" }
            };
        }
public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
        {
            return new List<IdentityResource>
    {
new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile(),
            new IdentityResources.Email(),
    };
        }

public  static List<TestUser> GetUsers()
        {
            return new List<TestUser>
    {
        new TestUser
        {
            SubjectId = "2",
            Username = "bob",
            Password = "psw",
             Claims = new List<Claim> {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "1@1.com"),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin")
                }
        }
    };
        }
```

With this request:

```
POST /connect/token
Headers:
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Body:
grant_type=client_credentials&scope=customAPI&client_id=oauthClient&client_secret=Password
```

the client got the access token. So my question is **how can I use the token**? What I need http-request to grab data about bob (test user)?

And there is another related question: how to config api to my client could access token for **specific** user only?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the configuration above, the client you have setup is using the ClientCredentials grant, this is an OAuth grant type.  If you wish to add identity you should look to use an OpenID Connect grant type, this will provide you with identity and tokens specific to the user you authenticate as.

More information on using OpenID Connect with Identity Server can be found in the docs at http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/3_interactive_login.html

Answer (score 0):

If you work through the following quickstart tutorials, you will see it come together.

- Setup and Overview
- Protecting an API using Client Credentials
- Protecting an API using Passwords
- Adding User Authentication with OpenID Connect
- Switching to Hybrid Flow and adding API Access back

(You can skip the one on External Authentication.)

https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/0_overview.html